# Under termux returns "unable to locate package"

Tags: android, termux

I have installed termux from google play store.
while giving command
"apt install update"
done E: unable to locate package update

what should I do now?
my phone is vivo y31L

Comment: Why is this a Python question?

Comment: `update` is not a valid package name. Try `apt install wget` and see what you get.

Answer (score 2):

install and update are two different options,and they're followed by pakage name.you may use like this:
apt install [pakage name] or
apt update [pakage name]